# How can I use auto increment variable in angular html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem to increment a span id.See the below scenario

```
<div class="full-height" id="" 
     ng-show="appGlobeObj.mode == 'test'" 
     ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <span id="spn0" class="divspan"></span>
</div>
```

How can I use the dynamic value in span id instead of 0 ?

Comment: Which dynamic value?

Comment: did you try ng-bind!!

Comment: Why do you need to increment id?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well what you want to achieve, you have to use:

```
<div class="full-height" id="" 
    ng-show="appGlobeObj.mode == 'test'" 
    ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <span id="spn{{ someDynamicValue }}" class="divspan"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside `ng-repeat`, you could use like this.

```
<div class="full-height" id="" 
     ng-show="appGlobeObj.mode == 'test'" 
     ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <span id="spn{{index}}" class="divspan"></span>
</div>
```

or else you should use a `counter` variable in your controller and `map` it to here

```
<span id="spn{{counter}}" class="divspan"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index.

```
<div class="full-height" id="" 
    ng-show="appGlobeObj.mode == 'test'" 
    ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <span id="spn{{$index+1}}" class="divspan"></span>
</div>
```